# Как проверить существует ли запись в бд с id 2 в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как проверить существует ли запись в бд с id 2 в yii2 ???

Comment: видимо стандартно- если запрос не вернул запись - значит нет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью метода `exists` можно это сделать, к примеру если речь идет о пользователе:

```
$isExists = User::find()->where(['id' => 2])->exists();
```

Результат будет `true` или `false`.